# Is there a quicker alternative to "gIntersection"?

Tags: r, gis, r-sp

I need to rapidly determine if a spatial polygon and a spatial line intersect. I am currently converting the polgon to a spatial line and using `gIntersection()`. Can anyone suggest a potentially quicker method? Perhaps using rasters instead of spatial line or something. I need to do this many thousands of times.

```
# .shp file to Spatial Line
polygon1 <- readShapeSpatial("C:.../SALandmass.shp")
polygon1filled <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(polygon1@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]),ID=1)))
SL <- as(polygon1filled, "SpatialLines")


# Test if line between two coordinates cross the shape
Pt1 = list(x = c(CurrentLong, MapCoordsm$x[i]), y = c(CurrentLat, MapCoordsm$y[i]))
SpatialLine1 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(Pt1$x,Pt1$y)), "L1")))
cross <- length(gIntersection(SpatialLine1, SL))
```

Comment: I would suggest to migrate this question to [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r), providing more context and codes.

Comment: how are defined your spatial lines? in which dimension are you reasonning and what have your tried so far?

Comment: I've never heard of `gIntersect()`. Perhaps you are asking about `gIntersects()`? How are you using it?

Comment: Try to put all your lines in one `SpatialLines` object, and all your polygons in a `SpatialPolygons` object, then call `gIntersection(lines, polygons, byid = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `gIntersection` returns a geometry with the intersection, `gIntersects` returns a logical indicating whether two geometries intersect.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input Edzer, and others.

I ran some test on your suggestions and it seems gIntersects() makes a huge difference. It is basically the same to convert the polygon to spatial lines first or just use the polygon.

Here are the test results:

```
# Original approach
system.time({           
    Pt1 = list(x = c(long1, long2), y = c(lat1, lat2))
    SpatialLine1 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(Pt1$x,Pt1$y)), "L1")))
    cross <- length(gIntersection(SpatialLine1, SL))
})

##  user  system elapsed 
##  0.53    0.00    0.53 

# Edzer suggestion: using gIntersects
system.time({           
    Pt1 = list(x = c(long1, long2), y = c(lat1, lat2))
    SpatialLine1 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(Pt1$x,Pt1$y)), "L1")))
    cross <- (gIntersects(SpatialLine1, SL))
})  

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.06    0.00    0.06            

# Edzer suggestion 2: using a polygon rather that spacial lines
system.time({           
    Pt1 = list(x = c(long1, long2), y = c(lat1, lat2))
    SpatialLine1 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(Pt1$x,Pt1$y)), "L1")))
    cross <- length(gIntersection(SpatialLine1, polygon1filled))
})  

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.43    0.05    0.48            

# Edzer suggestion 1&2: using a polygon rather that spacial lines and gIntersects
system.time({           
    Pt1 = list(x = c(long1, long2), y = c(lat1, lat2))
    SpatialLine1 = SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(Pt1$x,Pt1$y)), "L1")))
    cross <- (gIntersects(SpatialLine1, polygon1filled))
})              

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.06    0.00    0.07
```